# Handler чекбокса в форме react + typescript не работает корректно

Tags: reactjs, typescript

В родительском компоненте:

```
const checkTodo = (id: number) => {
    setTodos((prev) =>
        prev.map((todo) => {
            if (todo.id === id) {
                todo.isChecked = !todo.isChecked;
            }
            return todo;
        })
    );
```

В дочернем

```
<input type="text" onChange={changeHandler} onKeyPress={keyPressHandler} ref={refTitle} />
```

[Гит репозиторий с кодом](https://github.com/sudotrololo/react_ts)

При данной реализации функции инверсии состояния нажатости чекбокса он всегда возвращается в исходное состояние. Если переписать функцию без использования prev:

```
const checkTodo = (id: number) => {
    const newTodos = todos.map((todo) => {
        if (todo.id === id) {
            todo.isChecked = !todo.isChecked;
        }
        return todo;
    });
    console.log(newTodos)
    setTodos(newTodos)
};
```

все работает корректно. Но я хочу использовать prev. Подскажите где у меня ошибка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка была в `checkTodo`. В map нельзя мутировать объект (получается изменяется старый объект), нужно создавать новый  объект, модифицировать его и потом возвращать. Получается так:

```
const checkTodo = (id: number) => {
setTodos((prev) =>
  prev.map((todo) => ({
    ...todo,
    isChecked: todo.id === id ? !todo.isChecked : todo.isChecked,
  }))
);
```

};